# Exclude hidden files from Zip download in php

Tags: php, download, zip, hidden-files

I am using the following code in php to zip a folder and download all its files:

```
<?php

$the_folder = '/path/to/folder/to/be/zipped';
$zip_file_name = '/path/to/zip/archive.zip';

$download_file= true;
$delete_file_after_download= true; 

class FlxZipArchive extends ZipArchive {
    /** Add a Dir with Files and Subdirs to the archive;;;;; @param string $location Real Location;;;;  @param string $name Name in Archive;;; @author Nicolas Heimann;;;; @access private  **/

    public function addDir($location, $name) {
        $this->addEmptyDir($name);

        $this->addDirDo($location, $name);
     } // EO addDir;

    /**  Add Files & Dirs to archive;;;; @param string $location Real Location;  @param string $name Name in Archive;;;;;; @author Nicolas Heimann
     * @access private   **/
    private function addDirDo($location, $name) {
        $name .= '/';
        $location .= '/';

        // Read all Files in Dir
        $dir = opendir ($location);
        while ($file = readdir($dir))
        {
            if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue;

            // Rekursiv, If dir: FlxZipArchive::addDir(), else ::File();
            $do = (filetype( $location . $file) == 'dir') ? 'addDir' : 'addFile';
            $this->$do($location . $file, $name . $file);
        }
    } // EO addDirDo();
}
$za = new FlxZipArchive;
$res = $za->open($zip_file_name, ZipArchive::CREATE);
$basename = pathinfo($zip_file_name, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
if($res === TRUE) 
{
    $za->addDir($the_folder,basename($the_folder));
    $za->close();
}
else  { echo 'Could not create a zip archive';}

if ($download_file)
{
    ob_get_clean();
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private", false);
    header("Content-Type: application/zip");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$basename\"" );
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($zip_file_name));
    readfile($zip_file_name);
}
?>
```

Where should the condition be added to skip hidden files and folders? I am using the following function to check if the file/folder is hidden or not:

```
function is_hidden_file($path) { 

    $dir = "\"".$path."\"";
    $attr = trim(shell_exec("FOR %A IN (".$dir.") DO @ECHO %~aA"));
    if($attr[3] === 'h')
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution I found out so as to skip Actual hidden files and other files starting with '.' and '~' from being zipped and downloaded. It is working fine with windows 7, window 8 and windows 8.1.

```
<?php

    $the_folder = '/path/to/folder/to/be/zipped';
    $zip_file_name = '/path/to/archive.zip';

    $download_file= true;
    $delete_file_after_download= true; 

    class FlxZipArchive extends ZipArchive {
        /** Add a Dir with Files and Subdirs to the archive;;;;; @param string $location Real Location;;;;  @param string $name Name in Archive;;; @author Nicolas Heimann;;;; @access private  **/

        public function addDir($location, $name) {

            $this->addEmptyDir($name);

            $this->addDirDo($location, $name);
         } // EO addDir;

        /**  Add Files & Dirs to archive;;;; @param string $location Real Location;  @param string $name Name in Archive;;;;;; @author Nicolas Heimann
         * @access private   **/
        private function addDirDo($location, $name) {
            $name .= '/';
            $location .= '/';

            // Read all Files in Dir
            $dir = opendir ($location);
            while ($file = readdir($dir))
            {
                /************Putting the condition here restricts hidden files and files starting with '.' and '~'...***********************/
                if ($file == '.' || $file == '..' || $file[0]=='.' || $file[0]=='~' || is_hidden_file($location.$file)) continue;


                // Rekursiv, If dir: FlxZipArchive::addDir(), else ::File();
                $do = (filetype( $location . $file) == 'dir') ? 'addDir' : 'addFile';
                $this->$do($location . $file, $name . $file);
            }
        } // EO addDirDo();
    }

    function is_hidden_file($fn) {

        $dir = "\"".$fn."\"";
        $attr = trim(shell_exec("FOR %A IN (".$dir.") DO @ECHO %~aA"));
        if($attr[3] === 'h')
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    $za = new FlxZipArchive;
    $res = $za->open($zip_file_name, ZipArchive::CREATE);
    $basename = pathinfo($zip_file_name, PATHINFO_BASENAME);

    if($res === TRUE) 
    {
        $za->addDir($the_folder,basename($the_folder));
        $za->close();
    }
    else  { echo 'Could not create a zip archive';}

    if ($download_file){
    ob_get_clean();
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private", false);
    header("Content-Type: application/zip");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($zip_file_name) . ";" );
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($zip_file_name));
        if($delete_file_after_download){
            ob_clean();
            flush();
            if (readfile($zip_file_name))
                unlink($zip_file_name);
        }else{
            readfile($zip_file_name);
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi only one detail here.

If you want to delete the file after downloaded need to updated the last part of code with this:

```
    if ($download_file){
        ob_get_clean();
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Cache-Control: private", false);
        header("Content-Type: application/zip");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($zip_file_name) . ";" );
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header("Content-Length: " . filesize($zip_file_name));
        if($delete_file_after_download){
            ob_clean();
            flush();
            if (readfile($zip_file_name))
                unlink($zip_file_name);
        }else{
            readfile($zip_file_name);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing the flaw there :)